# AJAX function triggering callback function before click event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The following code handles a AJAX request, which after completion, passes the vehicle object values to the populateSummaryBlocks callback function. The callback function is set to listen for a click event, but the code is triggered immediately after the AJAX request is complete. What do I need to adjust in my code to prevent the immediate firing of the callback function and also disable the default behaviours of the buttons.

```
$("#get-rego").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var regoAjax = document.querySelector(".ajax-loader");
  addClass(regoAjax, "active");

  var plate = document.getElementById("input_2_6").value;

  var requestData = $.post({
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: {
      "action": "get_vehicle",
      "plate": plate,
    },
    "dataType": "json"
  });

  requestData.done(function(obj) {
    var response = obj.idh;
    var vehicleMake,
        vehicleModel,
        vehicleYear,
        vehicleColour,
        vehicleSubModel,
        vehicleBodyStyle,
        vehicleWofExpiry,
        vehicleRegoExpiry;

    removeClass(regoAjax, "active");
    removeClass(vehicleDetails, "gfield_conditionally_hidden");
    vehicleMake = response.vehicle.make;
    vehicleModel = response.vehicle.model;
    vehicleYear = response.vehicle.year_of_manufacture;
    vehicleColour = response.vehicle.main_colour;
    vehicleSubModel = response.vehicle.submodel;
    vehicleBodyStyle = response.vehicle.body_style;
    vehicleWofExpiry = response.vehicle.expiry_date_of_last_successful_wof;
    vehicleRegoExpiry = response.vehicle.date_of_last_registration;

    var vehicleDataSummaryOutput;
    vehicleDataSummaryOutput = "<div class=\"summary\">" +
      "<ul>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Make:</span> " + titleCase(vehicleMake) + "</li>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Model:</span> " + titleCase(vehicleModel) + "</li>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Year:</span> " + vehicleYear + "</li>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Colour:</span> " + vehicleColour + "</li>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Submodel:</span> " + titleCase(vehicleSubModel) + "</li>" +
      "<li><span class=\"label\">Body Style:</span> " + vehicleBodyStyle + "</li>" +
      "</ul>" +
      "</div>";

    document.querySelector(".vehicle-details").innerHTML = vehicleDataSummaryOutput;
    populateSummaryBlocks(response.vehicle);
  });

  requestData.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
  });
});

var customerName = document.getElementById("input_2_46_3").value;
var summaryBlocks = document.getElementsByClassName("summary-block");
var getQuoteSummaryBlock = summaryBlocks[0];
var mbiPaymentSummaryBlock = summaryBlocks[1];
var mbiWeekly = document.querySelector(".mbi-weekly");
var quoteLegalText = document.querySelector(".quote-legal-text");
var quoteNextButton = document.getElementById("gform_next_button_2_63");

function populateSummaryBlocks(vehicle, customerName) {
  var vehicleMake = vehicle.make;
  var vehicleModel = vehicle.model;
  var mbiWeeklyPrices = [
    "7.29",
    "11.74",
    "46.12"
  ];

  if(document.querySelector('input[name="input_52"]:checked').value = "standard") {
    mbiWeekly.innerHTML = mbiWeeklyPrices[0];
  } else if(document.querySelector('input[name="input_52"]:checked').value = "special") {
    mbiWeekly.innerHTML = mbiWeeklyPrices[1];
  } else {
    mbiWeekly.innerHTML = mbiWeeklyPrices[2];
  }

  removeClass(getQuoteSummaryBlock, "gfield_conditionally_hidden");
  removeClass(mbiPaymentSummaryBlock, "gfield_conditionally_hidden");
  removeClass(quoteLegalText, "gfield_conditionally_hidden");
  addClass(quoteNextButton, "is-enabled");

  document.querySelector(".quote-advice-content").appendChild(quoteNextButton);

  var vehicleMakeText = document.body.querySelectorAll(".vehicle-make-text");
  for (var i = 0; i < vehicleMakeText.length; i++) {
    var make = vehicleMakeText[i];
    if (typeof vehicleMake !== "undefined") {
      make.innerHTML = vehicleMake;
    }
  }

  var vehicleModelText = document.body.querySelectorAll(".vehicle-model-text");
  for (var i = 0; i < vehicleModelText.length; i++) {
    var model = vehicleModelText[i];
    if (typeof vehicleModel !== "undefined") {
      model.innerHTML = vehicleModel;
    }
  }

  var customerNameText = document.body.querySelectorAll(".customer-first-name-text");
  for (var i = 0; i < customerNameText.length; i++) {
    var name = customerNameText[i];
    if (typeof customerName !== "undefined") {
      name.innerHTML = customerName;
    }
  }
  document.querySelector("#getQuote").style.display = "none";
}
document.querySelector("#getQuote").addEventListener("click", populateSummaryBlocks, false);
```

Comment: This may not have anything to do with your problem but the if(document.querySelector('input[name="input_52"]:checked').value = "standard")  and  } else if(document.querySelector('input[name="input_52"]:checked').value = "special") should be using the == (comparison) not the single = (assignment) symbols.

Comment: You are invoking the method `populateSummaryBlocks(response.vehicle);`, so what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I've copied two lines to help you localize the second one.

```
document.querySelector(".vehicle-details").innerHTML = vehicleDataSummaryOutput;
populateSummaryBlocks(response.vehicle);
```

`populateSummaryBlocks` is invoked as well on click as on request ready. You need to invoke it only from onClick event listener.

---

You do disable default behaviour of the button by adding an event listener to it with prevent default method called on the event, like so:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Without defining it within the AJAX function, how can I pass the response.vehicles object values outside of the function for use in the populateSummaryBlocks function.

Comment: That sounds as kind of third question within one, and you can find thousands of answers to this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: The two functions need to work together. I wrote it using help on Stack Overflow about passing data from AJAX function to another function, but I am stuck with figuring out this issue.